# XPC Service not launching from Xcode Source Editor Extension (`still busy`)

Tags: ios, frameworks, xpc, xcode-extension

I was able to [set up my Xcode Source Editor Extension to work with XPC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67491522/35690).

When I run the app via Xcode for debugging purposes, everything works. My XPC extension is lauched.

I then Archived and distribute the project (for Development). After installing the extension and invoke a command, the XPC service never launches. I don't see it in Activity Monitor.

Additionally, the Xcode extension just shows the error:

> The command "Foo" is still busy.

Why would it be opening the XPC service correctly in debug mode, but when I distribute the app, it fails to launch the XPC service?

My XPC extension (and app) depends on a [shared framework I created](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html). Not sure if that is related to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to debug this is not necessarily by looking at the Console messages, but rather looking at the Crash Reports in the Console app. When I went there, I noticed that the XPC service was crashing every time it was run.

The crash was:

```
Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing
```

This made me realize I should double check the settings I used when [upgrading from Objective-C XPC to Swift XPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67491521/how-do-i-allow-my-xcode-source-editor-extension-to-use-xpc). In particular, the part I was confused about was when [the article](https://matthewminer.com/2018/08/25/creating-an-xpc-service-in-swift.html) said to set `Runtime Search Paths: @loader_path/../../../../Frameworks`. Turns out it should be added, not removed from the list.

I switched the XPC's Runpath Search Paths from:

```
$(inherited)
@loader_path/../../../../Frameworks
```

to

```
$(inherited)
@executable_path/../Frameworks
@loader_path/../Frameworks
@loader_path/../../../../Frameworks
```

And the XPC service no longer crashes.